# Get field value in java via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

How do I get the field value in java via reflection?

```
Class<?> clazz = someObject.getClass();
      Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields)
            {
                String fieldName=field.getName();
                var fieldValue=??

              }
```

Comment: Did you read the javadoc?

Comment: Not to mention you can copy paste your exact question title into google and get the answer, or even the links that pop-up on SO as you are typing the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object value=field.get(someObject)
```